# Sitecore Analytics Exceptions with mongoDB Failure

Tags: xdb, configuration, experience-analytics, mongodb

### Overview

During a disaster recovery test of our environment we make mongoDB unavailable to Sitecore with the expectation that Sitecore will continue to function normally due to the Configuration noted below per [Sitecore documentation](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/930657).

Instead what happens is the website throws exceptions making itself unavailable.  Additionaly, I can see a file created on the local CD server in the `Data/Submit Queue` folder, however after restoring mongoDB these files remain there rather than disappear as expected from being processed by Sitecore.

### Configuration

We are currently running Sitecore.NET 8.2 (rev. 170728) with a CM server and several CD servers.  I validated the following configuration on all of our CD servers:

Submit Queue Enabled:

```
<submitQueue patch:source="Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.config">
  <queue type="Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.SubmitQueue.FileSubmitQueue, Sitecore.Analytics" singleInstance="true">
    <param desc="folderPath">$(dataFolder)/Submit Queue</param>
  </queue>

  <backgroundService type="Sitecore.Analytics.SubmitQueueService, Sitecore.Analytics">
    <!--  Service wakeup interval in seconds.  -->
    <Interval>60</Interval>
  </backgroundService>
</submitQueue>
```

mongoDB set not to fail on read errors:

```
<mongo recoveryTimeout="60">
  <driver type="Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.MongoDbDriver, Sitecore.Analytics.MongoDB">
    <param desc="connectionString">$(0)</param>
    <param desc="failOnReadErrors">false</param>
  </driver>
</mongo>
```

### Exceptions

During the DR testing the CM servers continues to function online as expected, whereas the all CDs being to throw exceptions.  The following I believe to be the relevant problem from the Sitecore log:

```
ERROR Cannot create tracker.
Exception: System.TimeoutException
Message: A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = WritableServerSelector, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 } }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode : "ReplicaSet", Type : "ReplicaSet", State : "Connected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/mongoserver1:27017" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/mongoserver1:27017", State: "Disconnected", Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 123.123.123.123:27017
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.TcpStreamFactory.d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.TcpStreamFactory.d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.d__48.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.d__48.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.d__27.MoveNext()" }, { ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/mongoserver2:27017" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/mongoserver2:27017", State: "Disconnected", Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 124.124.124.124:27017
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.TcpStreamFactory.d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.TcpStreamFactory.d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.d__48.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.d__48.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.d__27.MoveNext()" }, { ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/mongoserver3:27017" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/mongoserver3:27017", State: "Connected", Type: "ReplicaSetSecondary", WireVersionRange: "[0, 4]" }] }.
Source: MongoDB.Driver.Core
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.ThrowTimeoutException(IServerSelector selector, ClusterDescription description)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.WaitForDescriptionChangedHelper.HandleCompletedTask(Task completedTask)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.WaitForDescriptionChanged(IServerSelector selector, ClusterDescription description, Task descriptionChangedTask, TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.SelectServer(IServerSelector selector, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Bindings.WritableServerBinding.GetReadChannelSource(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Bindings.ReadWriteBindingHandle.GetReadChannelSource(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.FindOperation`1.Execute(IReadBinding binding, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection.ExecuteReadOperation[TResult](IReadOperation`1 operation, ReadPreference readPreference)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection.FindOneAs[TDocument](FindOneArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.MongoDbCollection.c__DisplayClass2a`1.b__29()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.MongoDbCollection.Execute(Action action, ExceptionBehavior exceptionBehavior)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.MongoDbCollection.FindOneAs[TDocument](IMongoQuery query, ExceptionBehavior exceptionBehavior)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.MongoDbContactStorage.LoadContactIdentifier(ID id)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.MongoDbDataAdapterProvider.LoadContactIdentifierValue(ID contactId)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.MongoDbDataAdapterProvider.TryLoadContact(ID id, IContactFactory factory, LeaseOwner leaseOwner, TimeSpan leaseDuration)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Data.ContactRepository.TryLoadContact(Guid id, LeaseOwner leaseOwner, TimeSpan leaseDuration)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.ContactManager.TryLoadContact(Guid contactId, Int32 lockDurationMinutes, Boolean exclusive)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.EnsureSessionContext.LoadContact.Process(InitializeTrackerArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.EnsureSessionContext.EnsureSessionContextPipeline.Run(InitializeTrackerArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.DefaultTracker.EnsureSessionContext()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.CreateTracker.GetTracker.Process(CreateTrackerArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Initialize()
ERROR Application error.
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Tracker.Current is not initialized
Source: Sitecore.Analytics
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.StartAnalytics.StartTracking.Process(PipelineArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.StartAnalytics.StartAnalyticsPipeline.Run()
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics.Pipelines.MvcEvents.RequestBegin.StartTracking.Process(RequestBeginArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Routing.RouteHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

I would think this to be a separate issue, though since it occurs during the same timeframe of mongoDB being down I am posting this exception here as well.  I am not sure why WFFM would no longer be able to obtain a session (we use SQL for shared sessions).

```
WARN [WFFM] CurrentSession  is not initialized
ERROR SessionEndPipeline failed.
Exception: System.NullReferenceException
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source: Sitecore.Analytics.Automation
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.VisitEnd.RunAutomation.RunAutomationX(Database database)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.VisitEnd.VisitEndPipeline.Run(VisitEndArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.EndSession.SessionEndPipeline.Run(SessionEndArgs sessionEndArgs)
   at Sitecore.Web.Application.RaiseSessionEndEvent(HttpApplication context)
```

The question here being - why does Sitecore fail when mongoDB goes down when the configuration is defined to allow Sitecore to continue to function?

Comment: Have you contacted Sitecore Support?

Comment: Hi @TShiner, I am also facing the same issue. have you got any further details or fixes on how this issue can be solved?

Comment: @Sreekrishnan We were unable to resolve ourselves.  We created a ticket with Sitecore, who supplied a patch to resolve the issue.  I would contact Sitecore and reference support patch 147407.

Comment: Were you able to solve the issue? It seems the website you provided in the beginning of your question now contains the appropriate patches accordingly to your Sitecore version.